# std::map's behavior on referring to a key

Tags: c++, performance, search, dictionary, stdmap

I am writing a program for numerical simulation by using std::map to store some key-value pairs. The map is used as storing the states evoluted during the simulation. The type of the key is a integer and the value of corresponds to the key tells how many copies are there for the same keys, i.e. std::map. For each step of the simulation, I need to calculate how many values are there for the same key, so I will check that by the following code

```
if (map[key]>0) {do something here with the number of copies}
```

However, I soon find that this code doesn't work because even there is no such key in the map, whenever you call the map[key], it will generate a placeholder for that key and set the value as zero; therefore, I always overcount the total number of keys by std::map.size(). I later change the code as follow to search the key instead

```
if (map.find(key)!=map.end()) {...}
```

So is it the only and fastest way to check if a key exists or not for a map? I am going to run the simulation for hundreds millions times and it will call above code very often to check the key. Will it be too slow to use map.find() instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `find` member function is probably the fastest way to find whether a key is already in the map. That said, if you don't need to iterate over items in the map in order, you might get better performance with an `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: … for `int` keys and values, a simple array with occasional missing (unused) elements should also be considered.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I also thought to use array instead. But in my algorithm, for some condition, I need to remove/insert keys quite often so the total length varies.

Answer (score 1):

In a `std::map` or hashtable (`std::unordered_map`), the `find` function is very fast, as fast as using the `[]` subscripting operator.  In fact, it's faster when the element is not found, because it doesn't have to insert one.

Comment: thanks, it seems that the unordered_map is one solution. So the only difference between map and unordered_map is the key not sorted dynamically, right?

Comment: @user1285419: That's the only difference in usage.  Underneath, they are stored very differently (`std::map` is a balanced tree, while `std::unordered_map` is a hash table).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much difference in speed for various ways to check for existence of key. On the other hand: if your keys are integers and range is known, you might just use the array.

BTW:
I got interested about the speed of simple array, vector, map and unordered map. I have written simple program, that does 100000000 container[n]++, where n is a random number in range of 0 to 10000. The results:

- array: 1.27s
- vector: 1.36s
- unordered map: 2.6s
- map: 11.6s
  The overhead of loop + index calculation in this simple case is ~0.8s.

So it all depends on how much time is spent elsewhere. If it's considerably more (per 100000000 iterations) then it does not matter much what you use. But if it's not, it can be quite a difference.

Comment: I appreciate your spending time to show me the data. I think that give me some direction which structure am I suppose to use in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hash_map, it is the fastest data structures for your key-value type;

also you can use map,but it is slower than hash_map